# Remove left border of 2nd column in bootstrap 4 table

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have Bootstrap 4 table as below:

```
<table class="my-table table-bordered striped table">

  ......
</table>
```

I have two column layout, I would like to remove 2nd column left side border, any guess on this ?

This would include th (header) as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using css to select 2nd child of tr, then remove it left boder

```css
body{
  padding: 20px;
}

.my-table tr > *:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-left-style: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="my-table table-bordered striped table">
<tr>
   <th>header 1</th>
   <th>header 2</th>
   <th>header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>data 1-1</td>
   <td>data 2-1</td>
   <td>data 3-1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>data 1-2</td>
   <td>data 2-2</td>
   <td>data 3-2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this does not work for me, can you share codepen if you dont mind

Comment: that is for all the left side border not just one

Comment: it does for me but header gets red color, not the whole column left side also it still displays border

Comment: You want to remove 2nd column left side border (include th), this css code do exactly that thing. What do you want more than that?

Comment: can you make it worked for this snippet : https://codepen.io/mlms13/pen/CGgLF

Comment: it works only for left side of the table or right side of the table not in the middle, I show your example but mine is as the snippet i gave you

Comment: In your code, css define right border, you must hide right-boder, check this code:  table tr > *:nth-of-type(1) { border-right-style: hidden; }

Comment: Check this codepen, hope it helps: https://codepen.io/taimanh229/pen/BaLRMyw